# How to correctly loop over my JSON result?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, pdo

I am building an online web application where students can register for multiple workshops. When a student selects a workshop from the dropdown list I fire a AJAX Request to select the workshop details from my database. For connecting/querying  my database I use PHP PDO.

**ajax.handler.js**

```
 $("#trainingDropDown").change(function() {
       var dropDownValue = $(this).val();
       $(".accordion").empty();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                trainingName: dropDownValue
            },
            url: "pages/display_trainingen.php",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
});
```

When I alert data I get `[object Object],[object Object]`

**display_trainingen.php**

```
<?php
    require_once ("../classes/DBConnection.class.php");
    $dbConnection = new DatabaseConnection();

    $selectDetails = $dbConnection->dbConnection->prepare("SELECT idTraining, REPLACE(trainingName, ' ','') AS trainingName, DATE_FORMAT(trainingDay,'%d-%m-%Y') trainingDay, trainingStartTime, trainingEndTime, trainingClassRoom, trainingInfo FROM tbl_trainings WHERE trainingName = :trainingName");
    $selectDetails->bindParam(":trainingName", $_POST["trainingName"]);
    $selectDetails->execute();
    $selectDetailsArray = $selectDetails->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $jsonResult = json_encode($selectDetailsArray);
    echo $jsonResult;
?>
```

**Result JSON**

```
[
    {
        "idTraining": "1",
        "trainingName": "Meerzelfvertrouwen",
        "trainingDay": "06-01-2015",
        "trainingStartTime": "09:00:00",
        "trainingEndTime": "11:00:00",
        "trainingClassRoom": "A0.040",
        "trainingInfo": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue"
    },
    {
        "idTraining": "2",
        "trainingName": "Meerzelfvertrouwen",
        "trainingDay": "12-01-2015",
        "trainingStartTime": "09:00:00",
        "trainingEndTime": "11:00:00",
        "trainingClassRoom": "A0.041",
        "trainingInfo": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue"
    }
]
```

My question is how can I loop over my JSON result so that I get a nice `<ul>` with the all values off every JSON object? I you have any suggestions to my code I would love to hear them! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned data is serialised back to an array for you so a standard `for` loop can be used to iterate over it. From there, you can use standard jQuery methods to create the `ul` and `li` elements:

```
success: function(data) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var $ul = $('<ul />');
        $('<li />', { text: data[i].idTraining }).appendTo($ul);
        $('<li />', { text: data[i].trainingName }).appendTo($ul);
        $('<li />', { text: data[i].trainingDay }).appendTo($ul);
        $('<li />', { text: data[i].trainingStartTime }).appendTo($ul);
        $('<li />', { text: data[i].trainingEndTime }).appendTo($ul);
        $('<li />', { text: data[i].trainingClassRoom }).appendTo($ul);
        $('<li />', { text: data[i].trainingInfo }).appendTo($ul);
        $ul.appendTo('#myContainer');
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ymy1u0d/)